# Jemand findet sich irgendwo (wieder)

Tags: word-usage

Wenn ich schreibe, dass sich jemand an einem Ort *wiederfindet*, dann impliziert das *wieder-* [laut Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wiederfinden) (1.a. "sich im Straßengraben wiederfinden") eine gewisse Überraschung: eigentlich hatte die Person erwartet, anderswo anzulangen.

Wenn ich diese Überraschung aber nicht möchte, sondern mit *finden* ausdrücken will, dass jemand gerade dorthin gelangt, wohin er gelangen wollte, kann ich dann schreiben, dass er sich an einem Ort *findet*? Oder braucht *finden* in dieser Bedeutung unbedingt das *wieder*?

Kurz, ist das folgende Beispiel korrekt?

> Er betrat das Gebäude und fand sich in einem ovalen Raum.

Oder **muss** es heißen:

> Er betrat das Gebäude und fand sich in einem ovalen Raum wieder.

?

Comment: '... fand sich im Graben wieder' heißt dann soviel wie 'als er realisierte, was geschehen war'. Beim Gebäude-Betreten wäre ein ähnlicher Fall, dass jemand quasi sturzbetrunken hineingeht und irgendwann mit schwerem Kopf im Heizungskeller aufwacht. Jedenfalls müsste ein Irgendwie-Umherirren oder eine Ziellosigkeit inbegriffen sein: Er folgte anderen ins Gebäude und fand sich in einem ovalen Raum (wieder). Ohne 'wieder' für mich hochliterarisch und stilgewollt, nicht standardsprachlich, müsste (z.B. relativisch) fortgesetzt werden, Bedeutung ca. 'stand unversehens'.

Answer (score 3):

Um sich zu finden, muss man sich zuerst suchen - Oder sich die Frage "wo bin ich?" stellen - Das passt nicht besonders gut, wenn man genau dahin gegangen ist, wo man hinwollte.

Ich würde das Wort "finden" überhaupt nicht verwenden, wenn ich ausdrücken wollte, dass jemand zielgerichtet an einen Ort geht und dort ankommt, oder wenn schon, dann *befinden*. Wenn man genau dahin geht, wo man hinwollte kommt man eher an.

Also

> Er betrat das Gebäude und befand sich in einem ovalen Raum.
>
> Er betrat das Gebäude und kam in einem ovalen Raum an.
>
> Er betrat das Gebäude und erreichte einen ovalen Raum.

Answer (score 3):

Konstruktionen mit »finden« beinhalten nach meinem Dafürhalten grundsätzlich ein Überraschungsmoment. Um dies auszuschließen und die Aussage neutral zu halten, würde ich »sich sehen« verwenden.

> Er betrat das Gebäude und sah sich in einem ovalen Raum.

Oder noch etwas einfacher:

> Er betrat das Gebäude und stand in einem ovalen Raum.

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb heißt *wiederfinden*. Das ist etwas anderes als *wieder finden*. Von daher benötigst Du das *wieder* auch auf jeden Fall, weil Du sonst mit einem ganz anderen Verb arbeitest.

*Sich irgendwo wiederfinden* bedeutet, dass man (mehr oder weniger plötzlich oder überraschend) an einen Ort gelangt ist, was auch das Moment der Überraschung erklären würde, von dem der Duden spricht. In der Literatur wird das *sich an einem Ort wiederfinden* auch einleitend verwendet, um das Staunen über einen bis dato unbekannten Ort einzuleiten.

Das muss aber nicht unbedingt eine Überraschung im Sinne von "Huch!" sein, sondern kann auch einfach ein interessiertes Beobachten einer bis dato unbekannten Tatsache ausdrücken.

> Ich trat durch die Tür und fand mich in einem Flur wieder

Comment: Ich bestreite, dass es ausdrückt, dass man an diesem Ort noch nie war. Die Behauptung befremdet mich.

Comment: @userunknown Habe die Passage angepasst. Es ging mir darum, dass das "sich an einem Ort wiederfinden" in der Literatur gerne einleitend für die Beschreibung eines Ortes verwendet wird, der staunend erkundet wird. Beispiel: Narnia. In Schrank rein, in Narnia raus.

Answer (score 1):

Genau dafür gibt es den Ausdruck *sich irgendwo **be**finden*:

> Er betrat das Gebäude und befand sich in einem ovalen Raum.

Answer (score 0):

Das Problem hier scheint mir nicht nur das Verb zu sein, sondern auch der unbestimmte Artikel "einen". Bei

> Er fand sich in *dem* ovalen Raum wieder.

ist die Überraschung, die Ungewissheit verschwunden, insofern dass er sich nicht in *irgendeinem* Raum befindet, sondern einem bestimmten, bekannten. Allerdings sollte der Raum vorher im Text erwähnt worden sein.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass die Überraschung dadurch verschwindet. Bsp: »Er ging nach der Party betrunken ins Bett. Als er aufwachte, fand er sich im Wohnzimmer wieder.« Er kennt das Wohnzimmer, es ist ja sein eigenes. Trotzdem hat er nicht damit gerechnet, dort aufzuwachen.

Comment: Berechtigter Einwand. Ich habe meine Antwort bearbeitet und hoffe, sie ist jetzt passender.